# How can I open my links in one webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

I have a ListView of some websites. What I want is that when a user clicks on listview, those websites are shown in same webview instead of starting a new activity. How can I do that?

Here is my webview java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Aftonbladet extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) { // Enables browsing to previous pages with the hardware back button
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",
                true);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(pd.isShowing() && pd!=null)
                {
                pd.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For website loading in webview, you can use like this:

```
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
                 webview.loadUrl("http://www.linkedin.com");
                 webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
                    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

and your `MyWebViewClient` class is:

```
 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 
        @Override 
        //show the web page in webview but not in web browser
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
            view.loadUrl (url); 
            return true;
        } 
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It looks like what you want is to pass the url from one activity to another. To achieve that you can use either SharedPreferences or putExtras to the intent like this in your ListView Activity:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Aftonbladet.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("url", theURL);
    myIntent.putExtra(b);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

and then on your WebView Activity you can get that value:

```
    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = b.getString("url");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but my problem is to open the websites in my own webview activity. i have no problem with browser. i have a listview. when user click items on listview it should open the link in my own webview. For example 'myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");' i want it to change the url and start to webview activity when user clicks one of the items on listview.

Comment: So what you want is to change from one activity with a listView to another activity which has the webview?

Comment: exactly i want change the url and start webview

Comment: I just edited the answer with the solution I think you're looking for